# How to generate enumerator of enumerators

Tags: c#, .net

I'm learning DotNet. I can easy generate iterator over iterators on Python, but what is the canonical way to do it in C#? I create function `Slices` (not tested, may have bugs) but what looks dangerous for me is creation of segments (with `new`): if input sequence is very big then a lot of new segments will be created. I do it because: **1)** segment allow to keep size of slice - it can be cutted in the last slice **2)** I don't know is it possible to yield enumerators.

Alternative way may be to create only one segment and to reinitialize it on each iteration, but `ArraySegment` seems not supports such thing (so, may be custom struct is needed for segment).

```
public static IEnumerable<ArraySegment<T>> Slices<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, int sliceSize) {
    T[] slice = new T[sliceSize];
    IEnumerator<T> items = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    int from = 0, to;
    while (true) {
        for (to = from; to < from + sliceSize && items.MoveNext(); to++) {
            slice[from - to] = items.Current;
        }
        from = to;
        yield return new ArraySegment<T>(slice, from, to - from);
    }
}
```

So, what is the right or/and canonical way to generate iterator of iterators in C# (needed in slices, groups, etc)

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419019/335858) provide the information that you are looking for?

Comment: Another solution is to allocate one array (size = `sliceSize`) and to yield it on each iteration, but on last iteration if the last slice has size < sliceSize to allocate another array, so I'll have 2 allocations only. But what is the canonical way? What is the fastest way? New objects are allocated in heap, yield of struct - yields it from stack? Or?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In Python iterator is not a list - items can be readed from I/O, etc. As I know now, in C# too, so solution of splitting of lists is not the same

Comment: It seems like you'd want `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.  Also you might want to check out MoreLinq's `Batch` method. https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with returning `IEnumerator<T>` using `yield`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> 
     Slice<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int sliceSize)
{
    while(sequence.Any()) 
    {
        yield return sequence.Take(sliceSize);
        sequence = sequence.Skip(sliceSize);
    } 
}
```

Comment: The main issue here is the use of `Count` which potentially requires a full iteration of `sequence` and is problematic if `sequence` is an unending stream.

Comment: @juharr fixed that

Comment: In fact, this is very wrong to return the same enumerator. Every time you use .Any() or consume returned IEnumerable the initial stream will be re-created. That is if initial stream was stream of File lines or Db rows then it will be reopened or query will be re-executed. Please, try add logging to IEnumerable creation like in following fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/X0rA3v

Comment: @MaximKosov @juharr Either you want the possiblilty deferred execution or you don't. Add a `ToList()` if re-enumerating the original collection should be prohibited.